# how can I make a custom msg struct to publish?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, std-msgs, python3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i have a script that publishes a lot of system information like battery voltage/current, sysstem status, and isready all in all i have 13 different parameters im publishing. what i want is to tie all that data into a single sturct and only publish once.

for example something live geometry msgs odom msg, you know how it has like msg.pose.pose.x i want something similar like msg.data1.data

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/363719/how-can-i-make-a-custom-msg-struct-to-publish?/) by [MisticFury](https://answers.ros.org/users/58812/misticfury/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2020-10-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What you want is to create multiple custom msgs (for how to create custom msgs, see @JackB answer).

Then, you need to nest the messages the way you want. Something along the line of the following msg definitions:

`BatteryStatus.msg`:

```
float32 current
float32 voltage
```

`SystemStatus.msg`:

```
int32 error_code
string error_msg
```

`FullSystemInformation.msg`

```
BatteryStatus battery
SystemStatus system
```

And then you can access the fields like, e.g. `msg.battery.current` or `msg.system.error_code`.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2020-10-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-10-19**:
Or use [sensor_msgs/BatteryState](http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/BatteryState.html).